# Plotting 100% Stacked bar plot from many columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, group-by, bar-chart

I've been trying to solve this for a while now and tried virtually all related answers with no luck.

The original dataset I have looks like this:

```
| ID | Category | p0   | p1   | p2   | p3   | Target |
| 01 | A        | 0.92 | 0.01 | 0.05 | 0.02 | 0      |
| 02 | A        | 0.90 | 0.05 | 0.01 | 0.04 | 1      |
| 03 | B        | 0.88 | 0.08 | 0.03 | 0.01 | 0      |
| 04 | B        | 0.80 | 0.1  | 0.04 | 0.06 | 0      |
| 05 | B        | 0.90 | 0.01 | 0.03 | 0.06 | 3      | 
| 06 | C        | 0.92 | 0.02 | 0.03 | 0.03 | 2      | 
| 07 | C        | 0.78 | 0.12 | 0.04 | 0.06 | 1      |
| 08 | C        | 0.65 | 0.08 | 0.12 | 0.15 | 2      | 
| 09 | C        | 0.81 | 0.02 | 0.07 | 0.10 | 3      |
```

where `target` is the real value and `p0`,`p1`,`p2`,`p3` are the probabilities of each class.

My final goal is to make a stacked bar plot with `Category` in the x-axis and two groups of bars for each one, one with the `Target` percentages and one with the probabilities percentages. I have achieved the first part so far, which looks like this (in reality I have more targets and categories hence why it looks a bit off).
[image]

Basically, for the second set of bars, I'm stuck on the 100% stack part. I can group the probabilities by Category with this code, but can't figure out how to make it as a percentage of row total

```
df[['p0','p1','p2','p3','category','count']].groupby('category').sum()
```

where `count` is just a column that equals 1 in all rows.

If anyone has any idea of only the calculation and not the plot, please go ahead!!

Answer (score 0):

You can plot your barplots on the same ax and specify the position with kwarg `position` for each of them:

```
# target histogram
df_target = df.groupby(["Category", "Target"]).size()
df_target = (df_target / df_target.groupby("Category").transform(sum)).unstack(level='Target')
ax = df_target.plot.bar(stacked=True, position=1, cmap='Set2', width=0.25)

# probability histogram
df_prob = df[['Category', 'p0', 'p1', 'p2', 'p3']].groupby('Category').mean()
df_prob.plot.bar(stacked=True, ax=ax, position=0, width=0.25)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Note: you can change the color palettes to your liking